# What happens when the preprocessor sees SLOT(a) "1"#a

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, stringification

My understanding is the preprocessor `#define` replaces *identifier* with *replacement*

```
#define <identifier> <replacement>
```

Let's suppose we have the following:

```
#define SLOT(a) "1"#a

void myValue(int value);
SLOT(myValue(int));
```

I understand that `#` means *take the string literal*.  Thus, after the macro, wouldn't we have

```
"1""myValue(int)"
```

... essentially two string literals back to back.  I am guessing the preprocessor automatically concatenates two string literals back to back.  Is this true?  Where can I find information on this fact?

Comment: String literal concatenations are covered in the C++ 11 standard, specifically § 2.14.5 [lex.string], paragraph 13. You can read more about it (and a ton more about string literals) in that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your understanding is right.

1. `#` operator is stringizer operator.
2. Two string literals one after another separated by 0 or more white
   space characters are concatenated into single string literal.